# TypeScript erros with MVC system React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In order to setup some MVC pattern following
[this guide](https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2019-11-04-react-mvc/)
on my React Native project, I did separate my component work onto three parts:

The `AccountEditController` that will handle data submit, api call and navigation handling:

```js
export interface AccountEditProps {
  navigation: NavigationProp<any>;
  loading: boolean;
  onSubmit: (formData: UsersData) => void;
}

export const AccountEditController: FC = ({
  children
}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { client, handleError } = useClient();
  const { user, setUser } = useAppContext();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const onSubmit: AccountEditProps['onSubmit'] = (formData) => {
    setLoading(true);

    client.service('users').patch(user._id, formData)
      .then(ResultHelpers.toOne)
      .then((response) => {
        setUser(response);
        navigation.goBack();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        handleError(error);
      });
  };

  if (!React.isValidElement(children)) {
    return null;
  }

  return React.cloneElement<AccountEditProps>(children, {
    navigation,
    loading,
    onSubmit,
  });
}
```

A `AccountEditInfo` component that will use props provided by the controller plus two customs:

```js
import {
  AccountEditProps,
} from './AccountEditController';

export interface AccountEditInfoProps extends AccountEditProps {
  field: string;
  label: InputProps['label'];
}

export const AccountEditInfo: VFC<AccountEditInfoProps> = ({
  navigation,
  loading,
  onSubmit,
  field,
  label,
}) => {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const { user } = useAppContext();

  useEffect(() => setValue(user[field]), [user]);
  useEffect(() => setReady(Boolean(value)), [value]);

  const handleSubmit: ButtonProps['onPress'] = () => {
    const formData = {};
    formData[field] = value;
    onSubmit(formData);
  };

  return (
    <ScreenWrapper>
    <ScreenHeader
      title="Coordonnées"
      navigation={navigation}
      isStack
    />
    <ScrollView>
      <Input
        label={label}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={setValue}
        autoFocus
      />
      <Button
        title="Mettre à jour"
        onPress={handleSubmit}
        loading={loading}
        disabled={!ready}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  </ScreenWrapper>

  )
}
```

And then the implement on a screen component:

```js
const AccountInfoEditScreen: FC<AccountScreenProps<'InfoEdit'>> = ({ route }) => {
  const { field, label } = route.params;

  return (
    <AccountEditController>
      <AccountEditInfo
        field={field}
        label={label}
      />
    </AccountEditController>
  );
};
```

It works flawlessly, however TypeScript is complaining on the implementation part:

```
Type '{ field: string; label: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AccountEditInfoProps': navigation, loading, onSubmit ts(2739)
```

How can I properly make TypeScript understand that some props are already provided by the parent controller and should not produce any error?